# Insert into Oracle Table adds random characters to string when using SQL Server linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, oledb

I am trying to operate a simple INSERT command from my mssql host database into my oracle's linked server destination database.
Our environment is a mssql 2016 server on hostside, oracle 19c linked server database and linked server connection established.

I am trying to INSERT data into my orcle table:

X_PARTNO_BARC, structure as shown:

[image]

[image]

My Insert statement:

```
SELECT
CAST(A.ARANUMMER as varchar(20)) as PARTNO,
CAST(BC.BCCODE as varchar(40)) as EANNUM,
CAST('SQL' as varchar(20)) as CRTUSR,
CAST(format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss') as varchar(14)) as CRTDTM
INTO #tmptest
FROM BARCODES BC WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN AEL A WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.ARIDNR = BC.BCIDNR


INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (DC21WMS,'SELECT * FROM X_PARTNO_BARC') 
--(partno,eannum,crtusr,crtdtm)

SELECT * FROM #tmptest
```

My desired output is:

[image]

But then it adds these strange characters to my destination columns

[image]

What am i doing wrong?
i played a little bit with the column length on host side. eg. using varchar(max) instead. It changes the output but to other strings

Comment: Why are you using the fixed-length `CHAR` data type when your data all appears to be variable-length and should be stored in `VARCHAR2` data types? Also, your second image looks wrong as the data type does not match the first image.

Comment: That's a good question indeed! The oracle table was not set up by me - but that's a good point. I will try to alter it.

Comment: turns out I can't alter the data type. 
My workaround is to add spaces to my strings while inserting but this can't be a valid solution for this problem?

`INSERT INTO [DC21WMS]..[DC21WMS].[X_PARTNO_BARC]

SELECT
A.ARANUMMER + '                                       ' as PARTNO,
BC.BCCODE  + '                                        ' as EANNUM,
'SQL                                                  ' as CRTUSR,
CAST(format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss') as varchar(14)) as CRTDTM
--INTO #tmptest
FROM BARCODES BC WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN AEL A WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.ARIDNR = BC.BCIDNR`